# showing 2 custom attributes in 1 column catalog admin grid

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, attributes, adminhtml, grid

I add columns to the product admin grid with addColumn.

Is it possible to show 2 custom attributes in 1 column.

Something like this:

```
$this->addColumn('lev_vdm_inkoop',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('VDM'),
            'width' => '70px',
            'index' => array('lev_vdm_stock','lev_vdm_inkoop'),
    ));
```

Comment: Don't have time now, but the gist is to [add a custom renderer](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-renderer-magento-grid) to that grid column, using the `$row` object to get what attributes you need, as long as you define them in the grid collection object.

Comment: I have created a custom renderer for showing images. I will make a new custom renderer for this. Can I pass both attributes to the renderer or do I need to select the attributes in the renderer script?

Comment: Mage passes the `$row` param to your `render()` method. Check its data with `var_dump($row->getData())`. You should have *all* the row attributes/columns in there.

Comment: @RuudvanDijk did you ever fix this? I would be really interested in seeing a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it.
Rewrite the `_prepareCollection` method of the product grid and add this

```
    $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
        'lev_vdm_inkoop',
        "CONCAT_WS(' ', {{lev_vdm_stock}}, {{lev_vdm_inkoop}})",
        array('{{lev_vdm_stock}}'=>'lev_vdm_stock', '{{lev_vdm_inkoop}}'=>'lev_vdm_inkoop')
    );
```

After

```
->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

Then in the `_prepareColumns` add this:

```
    $this->addColumn('lev_vdm_inkoop',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Label goes here'),
            'index' => 'lev_vdm_inkoop',
        ));
```